# SQL Parse a JSON list into separate rows in another table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have telemetry data sent continuously to my Azure SQL database, which ends up in its landing table under the format:

```
INSERT INTO landing (ID, rawData)
VALUES
('Device1', [{"value1":"str1","value2":-109.0,"value3":3,"uselessvalue":16.0},{"value1":"str2","value2":-111.0,"value3":3,"uselessvalue":21.0},{"value1":"str3","value2":-113.0,"value3":2,"uselessvalue":18.0}]);
```

The amount of JSONs in the list can vary from 1 to several dozens.

I am trying to separate these values in definite rows in another table, so that they can be sent this way (within a trigger probably) :

```
INSERT INTO parsedData (ID, value1, value2, value3)
VALUES
('Device1', 'str1', -109.0, 3),
('Device1', 'str2', -111.0, 3),
('Device1', 'str3', -113.0, 2);
```

I have found several methods (split on commas, use WHILE loops, using keywords unsupported in Azure such as UNNEST) but I cannot find a way so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can unnest a JSON array with `openjson()`:

```
insert into parseddata (id, value1, value2, value3)
select l.id, x.*
from landing l
cross apply openjson(l.rawdata) with (
    value1 varchar(50)   '$.value1',
    value2 decimal(5, 2) '$.value2',
    value3 int           '$.value3'
) x
```

I had to make a few assumptions about the datatype within the json objects, that you might need to review.

Comment: Works great thank you! Would you know how to change the value2 type to smallint (even though the source value is a decimal)?
If I just change the data type to `smallint` but I get an error message indicating that the conversion failed, and I get another error message when trying to use `CAST`